# Create React App - loader error when trying to import from yarn workspace

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have a monorepository with 3 packages: gatsby app, CRA app and a components library.
Everything worked fine but at some point CRA started throwing errors:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3675:49)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

I was using rollup to bundle components lib, but removed it at some point because gatsby app was able to import from the workspace as is, without build (there is a link in node_modules). I thought it was the case, maybe CRA webpack is handling files in a different way, so I added back rollup, but it didn't help. I also tried using older versions of react-scripts (4.0.3 -> 4.0.1), it didn't help either.

Comment: Without any clear details on how to [reproduce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is not easy to figure out what's the matter.